# Can you help me to solve errors in this code?

Tags: c++, cin, cout, operation

I started studying C ++ recently and I'm trying to create a "calculator" with a few operations.
But I'm stuck in string 26 (cin >> choose;), which seems unresponsive. Why?

```
//CALCULATOR
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int start;
int choose;

int first;
int second;
int unic;

int result;

cout << "CALCULATOR (2 values)" << endl;
cout << "Click a botton to continue: " << endl;
cin >> start;
cout << "Write: " << endl;
cout << "- '1' for sum" << endl;
cout << "- '2' for subtraction" << endl;
cout << "- '3' for moltiplication" << endl;
cout << "- '4' for power of 2" << endl;

cout << "Your answer: " << endl;
cin >> choose;
cout << "________________________" << endl;

{ 
        if (choose=1, 2, 3)
        cout << "Insert the first value: " << endl;
        cin >> first;
        cout << "Insert the second value: " << endl;
        cin >> second;

    { 
        if (choose=1)
        result = first + second;
    }

    { 
        if (choose=2)
        result = first + second;
    }

    { 
        if (choose=3)
        result = first * second;
    
}

{ 
    if (choose=4)
    cout << "Insert the value: " << endl;
    cin >> unic;
    result = unic * unic;
}
}

cout << "Your result is: " << result;
}
```

It doesn't give me any errors, but it continues to execute all the "cout" operations I wrote, without giving me the possibility to write my values ​​with "cin".

Comment: What did you type in?

Comment: when it said "Click a botton to continue: " I typed a letter and I clicked enter. Then, it starts all the "cout" commands without "cin"

Comment: your compiler should give you some warning for this code. If not turn up the warning level. And dont ignore the warnings. `if (choose=3)` is assignment not comparison, it will always evaluate to `true` (and there are other mistakes, that I'd expect to trigger a warning)

Comment: So: you can look up what `cin >> number` does when the thing you typed isn't a number

Comment: uh ok, I'll try to solve the problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues in your code,

1. In C++ = stands for assignment to check value equivalency you have to use ==

```cpp
    if (choose = 1, 2, 3){
       ...
    // this doesn't work in C/C++
    // change it into 
    if (choose == 1 || choose == 2 || choose == 3)
```

2. When you have more than one line of code under a conditional (if/else or loops for/while) you will need to explicitly block them inside curly braces. So that changes if first if block into this

   ```
    if (choose == 1 || choose == 2 || choose == 3){
        cout << "Insert the first value: " << endl;
        cin >> first;
        cout << "Insert the second value: " << endl;
        cin >> second;
        ...
   ```
3. Same goes for the nested if condition.
4. Also there's no reason to take input for start.
5. If you fix all the errors you should get a code like this ->

```cpp
    //CALCULATOR
    #include <iostream>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    int main()
    {
        int start;
        int choose;
    
        int first;
        int second;
        int unic;
    
        int result;
    
        cout << "CALCULATOR (2 values)" << endl;
        cout << "Click a botton to continue: " << endl;
        // cin >> start;
        cout << "Write: " << endl;
        cout << "- '1' for sum" << endl;
        cout << "- '2' for subtraction" << endl;
        cout << "- '3' for moltiplication" << endl;
        cout << "- '4' for power of 2" << endl;
    
        cout << "Your answer: " << endl;
        cin >> choose;
        cout << "________________________" << endl;
    
        if (choose == 1 || choose == 2 || choose == 3){
            cout << "Insert the first value: " << endl;
            cin >> first;
            cout << "Insert the second value: " << endl;
            cin >> second;
    
            if (choose == 1)
                result = first + second;
    
            if (choose == 2)
                result = first + second;
    
            if (choose == 3)
                result = first * second;
        }
    
        if (choose == 4){
            cout << "Insert the value: " << endl;
            cin >> unic;
            result = unic * unic;
        }
    
        cout << "Your result is: " << result << endl;
    }
```

Footnote: Please use the given code as reference and try to understand the basics carefully. It is importat you do that.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I will try not to make these mistakes again.
P.S. I hadn't studied how to do this: "if (choose == 1 || choose == 2 || choose == 3)" so thanks for the explanation.